# User Destinations with Stomp, Spring Websockets, an External Broker with an External Consumer

Tags: apache-camel, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, stomp, spring-websocket

My Question centers around this slide from one of [Rossen Stoyanchev](https://spring.io/team/rstoyanchev) webinars.
[image]

When using a simpleBroker I can send messages to individual users with the /user/** destination format that is picked up in UserDestination and converted. I can also use it to send to a specific session, or all sessions of a specific user.

This is also possible when using an External Broker like ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ as long as the sender is also able to use /user/** or its helper annotations @SentToUser etc.

But, if I am not processing these messages locally and I have another consumer connected to the External Message Broker (Apache Camel for example) How do handle User specific messages and also reply at a user and session level?

Answer (score 1):

If the other consumer is in the same JVM you can have the "brokerMessagingTemplate" bean injected and use it to send messages to user-prefixed destinations.

For 4.2 we plan to support user destinations in a deployment with multiple web application servers connected to an External broker (see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11620). So if the other consumer is in a different JVM, then you could declare the @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker setup in that JVM as well or you could simple extend AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration if you don't need the WebSocket client bits.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Rossen. Using ActiveMQ as the broker, I expect the other endpoints to be running on different machines, so I shall await 4.2. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry Rossen, when you have some time, can you elaborate further. I've been trying to get 2 wars running in the same JVM, to share a brokerMessagingTemplate. Tried with MessageSendingOperations and SimpMessagingTemplate beans, and can't seem to get the non-websocket war to pass the message. should I be instantiating these beans in a special way in the non-websocket war? I could put the working MessagingTemplate bean in JNDI context and access it that way, but that seems overly complex to me.